# Al momento de crear un objeto su valor no cambia por una variable statica

Tags: java, poo, condiciones

Me encuentro realizando un ejercicio que dice lo siguiente:

generarRegistrationId(): este método se utiliza para generar una identificación de registro única para la certificación de cada estudiante. La identificación para los cursos regulares debe contener un número impar de 4 dígitos, comenzando con 1001. Para el curso acelerado, la identificación debe contener un número par de 4 dígitos.
Nota: La identificación de registro debe generarse tan pronto como se registra un estudiante (es decir, cuando se crea un objeto) y no es necesario que siga ninguna secuencia.

registrationId se basa de una variable estatica

```
*public static int counter;
static {
        counter = 1000;
    }*
```

lo que hize fue hacer un static block para su initializacion.

para lo de par e impar son estos metodos y asi los realize:

```
*public void generateRegistrationId() {
        
            if(RRTechnicalCertification.counter % 2 == 0) {
                this.setRegistrationId(counter + 1); 
            }
            else {
                this.setRegistrationId(counter + 2);
            }
        }*  


*public void generateRegistrationId() {
                    
                if(RRTechnicalCertification.counter % 2 == 0) {
                    this.setRegistrationId(counter + 2); 
                }
                else {
                    this.setRegistrationId(counter + 1);
                }
            }*
```

al momento de crear objetos el id es el mismo para todos
Regular Course Registration Details

---

Student Name   :Roland
Course Name    :Java
Course Duration :6
Registration ID :1001
Fees : 11400.0

Regular Course Registration Details

---

Student Name   :Roland
Course Name    :Java
Course Duration :6
Registration ID :1001
Fees : 11400.0

Crash Course Registration Details

---

Student Name   :  Dante
Course Name    : Python
Registration ID : 1002
Fees 5618.0

Crash Course Registration Details

---

Student Name   :  Dante
Course Name    : Python
Registration ID : 1002
Fees 5618.0

habia leido que los valores estaticos son los mismos para los objetos, me pueden ayudar en entender mejor como funcionan los valores estaticos? se que son de nivel clase, pero porque se mantiene el mismo para todos?

Comment: Las variables estáticas son variables compartidas por todas las instancias de una clase. Todas las instancias de la clase tendrán el mismo valor (solo existirá uno para todos), y si cambia para uno, cambia para todos. Lo que debes hacer en tu caso, con el objetivo de que cada estudiante tenga un id diferente, es incrementar la variable counter al final de cada uno de los métodos `generateRegistrationId`. Piensa siempre en las variables estáticas como una variable global que se puede acceder en todos los objetos de la clase.

Comment: trate desde el constructor, porque sonarLint me dijo que lo hiciera aparte, me fui a la superclase ya que estas estos metodos pertenecen a subclases, lo que hize fue crear un bloque estatico donde lo inicialize a 1000 y en el constructor le fue counter++ para que cada vez que se cree un objeto, cambio un poquito, pero creo que entendi

Comment: Al final no dejaste muy en claro cual es tu pregunta, ya que la respuesta es muy global, cualquiera te mandaria un enlace o que busques un video sobre ello.

Comment: osea mi pregunta es... como puedo cambiar el numero de REGISTERID, porque el valor del Id, proviene de una variable estatica, osea pasa esto objeto1 = 1000 objeto2 = 1000 objeto3 = 1000, lo que quiero es objeto1 = 1001, objeto2 = 1002, objeto3 = 1003, y asi sucesivamente